# How to install python 3rd party librarys in visual studio code?

Tags: python, text, visual-studio-code, editor, libraries

I am trying to import pyautogui in visual studio but it's not recognising it.

How to add python libraries in visual studio code?
And is there a better text editor which I can use?

Comment: Is there an error you get when running the file? otherwise ensure you installed using pip

Comment: All you need to do is type pip install pyautogui in the command line before starting VScode. If you are using the Anaconda distribution of python use: conda install  pyautogui  Do one of them from the command line before starting VScode.  If this doesn't work just leave a comment and I'll try to help.